# Python 3.8.2 | Why does my input doesn't accept my answer even if it's a valid one? (function)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm a beginner in Python. I want to create a textual game, with some MCQ in it, and to save some code, I created a function which asks and wait for an answer (input()) but it can just accept some answers (e.g. a, b, c, d...), but if it isn't a valid answer, it repeats the question (while loop). It works, but even if I answer correctly, it's repeating. Can you help me please?

Here is the function,

```
def carsaction(*instructions):
    """
    Fonction servant à faire un choix pour interagir avec soi même.
    """
    commande = str(None)
    while commande.lower() != instructions:
        commande = str(input("Quelle action choisissez-vous?"))
        if commande.lower() == instructions:
            break
        else:
            print("Réponse non valide!")
            time.sleep(3)
            continue
```

And when I use it:

`carsaction("a","b")`

___ This is something else

```
    print("Vous vous trouvez quelque par. Que faites-vous?")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("""
        a: Explorer
        b: Regarder l'inventaire
        """)
    carsaction(["a","b"])
    if carsaction(["a"]) == "a":
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Vous voulez donc explorer.")
        time.sleep(3)
        [code after...]
    else:
        print("Test")
```

Answer (score 0):

`instructions` is a list, so you should use `if commande.lower() in instructions`

For the same reason, the criterion in your `while` won't ever be false (even though with the `break` statement, it's actually useless). `while commande.lower() not in instructions:` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
def carsaction(*instructions):
    """
    Fonction servant à faire un choix pour interagir avec soi même.
    """
    commande = str(None)
    while commande.lower() not in instructions:
        commande = str(input("Quelle action choisissez-vous?"))
        if commande.lower() in instructions:
            break
        else:
            print("Réponse non valide!")
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a list as a parameter containing the valid characters as elements, and make your while loop check if the user input is one of your valid characters in your list, but your code tries to match the whole function parameters with the input rather than only one or more.

To solve this, you should create a list as a parameter and use `in` operator when defining the check loop.

```
def carsaction(instructions):
    """
    Fonction servant à faire un choix pour interagir avec soi même.
    """
    user_input = str(None)
    while user_input not in instructions:
        user_input = input("Your input: ")
        if user_input in instructions:
            break
        else:
            print("not valid")
            continue




carsaction(["a","b","c"])
```

Comment: Check the third code please to see if I solved the problem, as you see, I'm not really good at english =^(

Comment: you can also add .lower() for uppercase inputs.

Comment: Now the problem is that when we choose a valid answer, nothing occurs, when he is supposed to execute code. I'll show you the code

Comment: The first time, it doesn't work, and after, it's doing the else case.

Comment: Nothing occurs since my code doesn't include anything but break statement under the if block. Add what you want to see under the if block when the input is valid, and check the code again whether it works or not.